# How to properly inspect debuger?

Tags: c, loops, debugging, gdb

I am debugging this:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <ctype.h>
  4 
  5 char *up(char*);
  6 
  7 int main(){
  8    char initstr[20];
  9    printf("enter string\n");
 10    fgets(initstr,20,stdin);
 11 
 12    char *str=up(initstr);
 13    printf("%s\n",str);
 14 }
 15 
 16 char *up(char *in){
 17    char *ret;
 18    for(;*(in++)!='\0';*(ret++)=toupper(*(in++))); //this is inspecting
 19    return ret;
 20 }
```

and this is how I debugged:

===============================================================
+

```
set history remove-duplicates 256
Reading symbols from a.out...done.
6   in /home/shepherd/Desktop/bin/a.c
+b 12
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1181: file a.c, line 12.
+r
Starting program: /home/shepherd/Desktop/bin/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:12
+s
up (in=0x7fffffffdc40 "abc\n") at a.c:18
+awatch in
Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in
+awatch ret
Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 3: ret
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Value = 0x7fffffffdc40 "abc\n"
0x00005555555551de in up (in=0x7fffffffdc40 "abc\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc40 "abc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc41 "bc\n"
0x00005555555551e6 in up (in=0x7fffffffdc41 "bc\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc41 "bc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n"
0x00005555555551b7 in up (in=0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Value = 0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n"
0x00005555555551bb in up (in=0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n") at a.c:18
+s
__GI_toupper (c=99) at ctype.c:53
+s
+s
__GI_toupper (c=99) at ctype.c:51
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 3: ret

Value = 0x7fffffffdc60 ""
0x00005555555551ce in up (in=0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 3: ret

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc60 ""
New value = 0x7fffffffdc61 "RUUUU"
0x00005555555551d6 in up (in=0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Value = 0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n"
0x00005555555551de in up (in=0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc42 "c\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc43 "\n"
0x00005555555551e6 in up (in=0x7fffffffdc43 "\n") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc43 "\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc44 ""
0x00005555555551b7 in up (in=0x7fffffffdc44 "") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 2: in

Value = 0x7fffffffdc44 ""
0x00005555555551bb in up (in=0x7fffffffdc44 "") at a.c:18
+s
__GI_toupper (c=0) at ctype.c:53
+s
+s
__GI_toupper (c=0) at ctype.c:51
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 3: ret

Value = 0x7fffffffdc61 "RUUUU"
0x00005555555551ce in up (in=0x7fffffffdc44 "") at a.c:18
+s

Hardware access (read/write) watchpoint 3: ret

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc61 "RUUUU"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc62 "UUUU"
```

I know there is a lot of output, And tl;dr, but its basically debuggin the for loop, and how two variables `char* in` and `char *ret`. The point is, I want to go by every char in `in` and make it uppercase, and reassing it back to `ret` all in one loop head.

Now, as I can see from the debugger, in the first loop step, there is `reading` (for condition of the loop) of the `in`, and `writing` (action at the end of every loop step), but there is no modification(writing) to the variable `ret`, which should be written also at every end of the loop (as the thrid argumtn of the loop head -> `*(ret++)=toupper(*(in++))`), so why it is not? Also, there is some strange behaviour in the debugger, where 2 times is read/write the variable `in`, and only *once* is read/write variable `ret`, but the loop step is equal for both variables. So how to properly debug?

Comment: Why do you want to do everything in the loop head? The code would be more readable if you just wrote out a normal `for` loop.

Comment: `ret` was not initialized.

Comment: @ssbssa yes, that was bad mistake, but I have repost it here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62233572/how-to-change-single-char-in-string-array, where it could be better to read