# how to change single char in string array?

Tags: c, loops, debugging, gdb

Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *up(char *);

int main() {
    char initstr[20];
    printf("enter string\n");
    fgets(initstr, 20, stdin);

    char *str = up(initstr);
    printf("%s\n", str);
}

char *up(char *in) {
    char *ret;
    for (ret = in;
         *in != '\n'; 
         *(ret++) = toupper(*(in++))
        );
    return ret;
}
```

Run it as:

```
$./a.out
enter string
abc

#only new line from `printf("%s\n",str);`
```

From debugger

```
Hardware watchpoint 3: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc20 "abc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc21 "bc\n"

Hardware watchpoint 2: ret

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc20 "abc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc21 "bc\n"

Hardware watchpoint 3: in

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc21 "bc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc22 "c\n"

Hardware watchpoint 2: ret

Old value = 0x7fffffffdc21 "bc\n"
New value = 0x7fffffffdc22 "c\n"
...
```

I can see that both variables are reducing, but I wanted to change the `ret` *inline*, char by char. But at the end (after loop), the `ret` is reduced to nothing, and the program will only output `\n`. So how can I achieve this in the loop head?

EDIT:
Thanks to answer below, having in mind I have to return first address of pointer, I can implement loop_head-only function by this:

```
char *up(char *in){
    char *ret;
    size_t size=strlen(in);
    for(ret=in;
         *in!='\n'; 
         *(ret++)=toupper(*(in++))
        );
    return (ret-size+1);
}
```

Comment: Your `up` function should either change the string in-place, in which case there is no need to return anything, or it should return a modified copy of the string, leaving the original string unchanged.  Yours is returning a pointer to the end of the original string, which makes no sense.  Why does it even have both `ret` and `in` when they both have the same value throughout the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug in `up` is you increment `ret` all the way to the newline (`\n`) and return `ret` pointing to this character in the string. You should instead return a pointer to the initial character.

- It is simpler to write this function using an index.
- packing all the logic into the `for` clauses with an empty body is hard to read and error prone.
- Note also that the string might not contain a newline, so it is safer to stop at the null terminator, the newline will not be changed by `toupper()`.
- Finally, you should not pass `char` values to `toupper()` because this function and all functions from `<ctype.h>` is only defined for values of type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. On platforms where `char` is signed by default, the string might contain negative `char` values which may cause undefined behavior when passed to `toupper()`. Cast these as `(unsigned char)` to avoid this issue.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *up(char *s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
         s[i] = toupper((unsigned char)s[i]);
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char initstr[20];
    printf("enter string\n");
    if (fgets(initstr, sizeof initstr, stdin)) {
        char *str = up(initstr);
        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's terrible. I mean the fact that *toupper* is not guaranteed to handle all values properly. Everything outside of a to z could be ignored. +1 for letting us know.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: indeed `toupper()` takes an `int` argument, but not all `int` values are legal, only those between `0` and `UCHAR_MAX` in addition to the negative value `EOF` (usually `-1`). It is dreadful that negative `char` values may cause undefined behavior or may be confused with `EOF` (as `'\xff' == EOF` on many platforms). This is a fundamental inconsistency in the C library. The safe approach to this is to configure the compiler to make `char` unsigned by default, if possible. For example: `gcc -funsigned-char`

Comment: @chqrlie I know it is solution, but I still want the implementation by loop head only, no body (just to see the difference). Can you do so?

Comment: But has to be `ret-size+1`? plus one at the end? When I insert `abc\n`, then at then and of the loop the address of `ret` is `ret+4` (abc and increment when see `\n`, but finishes the loop). So when I return address (`ret-size+1`), then it is equivalent to `ret + 4 (by the loop) - 4 + 1 == ret+1`, not `ret`.

Comment: @autistic456: your fix is still very brittle: the string might not contain a `'\n'`, the input stream might contain a single line without a newline. Furthermore you do not check for `fgets()` success, so you get undefined behavior on an empty file. If you insist on your loop structure, use `char *ret; for (ret  = in; *in != '\0'; *in = toupper((unsigned char)*in), in++) ;`